# Styles not updating to instance documents from master template

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, microsoft-word-2019

I have a master styles .dotx file which is attached to all of my .docx instance documents. 'Automatically update document styles' is ticked. I have modified the Table Of Contents (TOC) styles so that there is no white space between each TOC entry – see the first below screen snip.

[image: Text]

However, these do not seem to be carried forward into my instance documents for levels 7, 8, and 9 of the TOC – see the second below screen snip.

[image: Text]

Does anybody have any ideas?

Many thanks in advance,

Keith

Comment: I don't see the similarities between the two styles from your screenshots. Anyway, I suggest you delete the original template file and reset it again.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the methods shown in [Shauna Kelly's page](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) on this to attach your numbering to styles. This is a vital starting point.

Styles attached to numbering are among the most finicky when it comes to copying them. However it can be done.

See my page on [A Global Stylesheet in Microsoft Word?](http://www.addbalance.com/word/stylesheet.htm) There is a related [sample](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#GlobalStylesheet) available for free download.